# Intersection between a disk and a mesh

Tags: geometry, circles

Consider a wire mesh with infinitesimally small wire and spacing of dimensions $a$ and $b$, with a disk dropped on it of radius $r$, with its centre at $(x,y)\in[r,r+a]\times[r,b+r]$, where the axis are defined as the nearest wires below and to the left of the circle respectively, as shown here?

[image]

Is it possible to derive a function which expresses the total length of wire in contact with the interior of the disk as a function of $x,y,a,b$ and $r$, which works for all possible values, ideally with no assumptions being made about the relative sizes of $r$, $a$ and $b$? Anything will be considered helpful, not matter how messy or what approximations need to be made.

Comment: If the point $(x,y)$ is chosen uniformly at random in the available region, then the expected amount of wire covered is exactly $\pi r^2(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b})$. Do you need a more precise function in terms of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: It's generally considered good form to edit [unclear questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317174/contact-between-a-circle-and-a-mesh#comment6824764_3317174) so that they make more sense rather than delete them and repost the entire question again. For instance, people might have been in the process of writing answers to that post, and now whatever they wrote is all gone.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the option to edit until after I deleted it, i need to be more observant.

Comment: @Maths3457689 No problem. You're new here, I don't expect you to know everything about the math.SE culture on your first day. Just something to keep in mind for next time.

Comment: @Magma I would have expected it to depend on $x$ and $y$?

Comment: The value I gave is the average over all valid $x$ and $y$. So you do need it in terms of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: yes, I am looking for an expression which is valid not matter how coarse or fine the mesh is.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I found. First of all, you need to count the number of wires inside the circle. This number is the sum of numbers of wires south/north/west/east of the center. These are
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \#W_{\mathrm{south}} &=& \left\lfloor \frac{y}{b} \right\rfloor,\\
    \#W_{\mathrm{north}} &=& \left\lfloor \frac{y+r}{b} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{y}{b} \right\rfloor,\\
    \#W_{\mathrm{west}} &=& \left\lfloor \frac{x}{a} \right\rfloor,\\
    \#W_{\mathrm{east}} &=& \left\lfloor \frac{x+r}{a} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{x}{a} \right\rfloor
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is rounding towards zero function.

By pythagorean theorem, the length of chord at $h$ from center is
$$
    L_{\mathrm{chord}} = 2\sqrt{r^{2}-h^{2}}.
$$

Therefore, you sum everything getting total length $L=L_{\mathrm{south}}+L_{\mathrm{north}}+L_{\mathrm{west}}+L_{\mathrm{east}}$ where
\begin{eqnarray*}
    L_{\mathrm{south}} = 2\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\#W_{\mathrm{south}}-1} \sqrt{r^{2}-(y-b(\#W_{\mathrm{south}}-k))^{2}},\\
    L_{\mathrm{north}} = 2\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\#W_{\mathrm{north}}} \sqrt{r^{2}-(y-b(\#W_{\mathrm{south}}+k))^{2}},\\
    L_{\mathrm{west}} = 2\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\#W_{\mathrm{west}}-1} \sqrt{r^{2}-(x-a(\#W_{\mathrm{west}}-k))^{2}},\\
    L_{\mathrm{east}} = 2\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\#W_{\mathrm{east}}} \sqrt{r^{2}-(x-a(\#W_{\mathrm{west}}+k))^{2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Wow, great, that seems to make sense!